# How do I attach to a process in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, shell

I am working with a large Java program that uses a command line shell to run integration tests.  How do I attach eclipse to that process?  Do I have to run the process and then attach it?  It would be great to attach it to the shell process before I run it.

Comment: "Attach?"  You mean like for debugging?  Or something else?

Comment: If you mean remote debug then launch your java process with "-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8765" and in Eclipse use "Remote Java Application" with Socket Attach, the correct project and the port above (address would be localhost for local process). More on the subject in the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you start your integration tests, add the following arguments to Java.

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y
```

The `suspend=y` will pause startup until you attach with the debugger.  In Eclipse, go to Run => Debug Configurations.  Create a new "Remote Java Application" configuration and specify localhost as the host and 8000 as the port.